# Get android paid app purchase date

Tags: android, google-play, purchase-order

Let's assume I have a paid app purchased by a user (I don't use In-app Billing). Is it possible to execute a piece of code on his device to get the date at which this user has purchased my app?

Comment: Just curious, any particular reason you want this or how would you use this information?

Comment: @Anonsage This can be useful to enable/disable legacy features for early purchasers of the product. For example, I used to include X, but then I replaced it with Y for new users, but I want to give the previous users both X and Y to avoid any drama... And it must survive a delete / re-install / new device etc.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't 100% answer to your question, but you can get the time and date of the first install of the app

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#firstInstallTime

```
long installTime = context.getPackageManager()
                   .getPackageInfo("com.some.package.name", 0)
                   .firstInstallTime;
```

Comment: To expand on this, use `new Date(getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.some.package.name", 0).firstInstallTime).toString();` to return a user readable date.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I haven't yet tried but do you know what they mean by first install (i.e. what is the value returned if the app is uninstalled/installed multiple times)?

Comment: From the JavaDoc `The time at which the app was first installed. Units are as per currentTimeMillis().` , why don't you test it out and write the code then uninstall & reinstall, post your findings here for others

Comment: I have tested, unfortunately the time returned is purely local and not correlated to the play store purchase: reinstalling the app returns a fresh value :(

Comment: Well what you could do, is save the date when they install, then use the [Backup Manager]( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/backup/BackupManager.html) to Persist this value across installs?